# Why Rails app showing database information at the bottom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a blog. And whenever I added a post, there is always a list of record from the database showing at the bottom of the post index page (`home.html.erb`), like this:

```
[#<Post id: 1, title: "hahaha", content: "Because the gravatar_for method is undefined, the u...", public: true, created_at: "2013-03-18 04:00:17", updated_at: "2013-03-18 04:01:09">]
```

I've tried to remove `<%= will_paginate @posts %>` but it doesn't work.

Here's my `home.html.erb`:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
<article class="posts">
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h1>
    <h3><%= post.public %></h3>
    <p><%= truncate markdown(post.content), length: 400, omission: " ......" %></p>
    <span class="continue"><%= link_to "... Continue Reading ...", post_path(post) %></span>
</article>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Here's my Gemfile just in case you need it:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'pg'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'coderay'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker' 
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

This is a weird situation. So I want to know what happened?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your template file from -

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
<article class="posts">
  <h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h1>
  <h3><%= post.public %></h3>
  <p><%= truncate markdown(post.content), length: 400, omission: " ......" %></p>
  <span class="continue"><%= link_to "... Continue Reading ...", post_path(post) %></span>  
  </article>
  <% end %>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

to -

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <article class="posts">
  <h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h1>
  <h3><%= post.public %></h3>
  <p><%= truncate markdown(post.content), length: 400, omission: " ......" %></p>
  <span class="continue"><%= link_to "... Continue Reading ...", post_path(post) %>  </span>
 </article>
<% end %>
```

It shows up because you are using <%= @posts.each do |post| %> instead of <% @posts.each do |post| %>. <%= %> will output the return but <% %>  won't

Answer (score 4):

You need to change this:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
```

to this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

The `<%=` tells it to append the output to the HTML, which is why you're seeing the array.